# Is the inside of Stainless faucet also stainless?

Tags: faucet

I have this supposedly stainless faucet.

[image]

But when I peek inside. It doesn't look stainless, or maybe it's the rust sticking to the surface.

[image]

If a faucet is advertised as stainless. Is it stainless all the way (outside and inside)?

Comment: it may be copper alloy ... it doesn't have to be steel to be stainless

Comment: Does it say "stainless" or "stainless steel"?  Most faucets are made from brass which is then plated with chrome or nickel to make it silver-colored.

Comment: here it says Chrome.. is it chrome all the way to inside? https://www.amazon.com/Faucet-26602LF-Single-Handle-Kitchen/dp/B00D5YWE8Y

Comment: here it says finish is chrome.. what is inside? https://www.deltafaucet.com/kitchen/product/26602LF

Comment: Almost certainly brass, with chrome plating. Even if it WAS stainless steel, that's a "finish" in plumbing fixtures and does not imply that the water passages are stainless steel throughout. But chorme or nickle finishes are virtually always plated on brass in plumbing fixtures, unless they are the low-end fixtures (Chrome plastic.)

Comment: Are there pure 100% stainless steel faucet? There is a baby at home and we need utmost clean waters to wash milk bottles. Its dirty inside my existing and i cant wash the inside. It looks corroded already. Any idea how to clean the inside of any corrosion?

Comment: @jtl stainless STEEL rusts. You're overthinking this. You should try to see what a used plumbing pipe looks like on the inside.

Answer (score 0):

That is a difficult = expensive shape to make in stainless steel, so I doubt it is stainless. Solid chromium is never made as a product.  The picture shows a gold color in the inside indicating a copper alloy. I suspect it is a German Silver ; a brass with 10 to 20 % nickel which makes it silver color ,no plating. These alloys are fine for water service. Do you have a problem ?

Comment: My house water pipes are GI and rusty. Im afraid the rusts have stuck to the inside. Can such alloy rust by themselves? I plan to replace the entire faucet with others (these things cost $200 or so) after installing sediment filters before it. There is a baby and we need utmost clean water to wash the milk bottles for example.

Comment: If I am correct and it is German Silver, or any other copper alloy, any corrosion products ( due to water) would be some shade of green/blue.

Comment: Rusts passed by it for 10 years. Can it stick to the surface? I just put sediment filters before faucet. Will the rusts stuck on the inner surface come out little by little for months or a few times only? What you think?

Comment: Iron oxides are much more likely to settle in low spots than stick somewhere , once loose from their source.